# What does "You feel lucky" mean?

Tags: ascendant

Some of the weapons I've found say "You feel lucky". What does that mean?

Answer (score -2):

It's probably a reference to the movie [Dirty Harry](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Dirty_Harry).

> [...] But being this is a .44 Magnum, the most powerful handgun in the world, and would blow your head clean off, you've got to ask yourself one question: **'Do I feel lucky?' Well, do ya, punk?**

Unless it's not a firearm of any kind.

Comment: It's not, although that would be a clever usage of that phrase